# Strong and Weak Dominance Table

Tags: game-theory

I have this table, 2 agents and I want to find for each agent if any action is strongly or weakly dominated. This is the table:

[image]

Now, i've found a solution but I'm not sure if it's correct. So for let's say agent 1(the one handling rows): 1<2<2, 1<3<4 and 0<3<4 so I don't have a strong dominance.

For agent 2: 1<=1<=1, 2<5<6 and 2<3<4 which means that I don't have strong dominance here too.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Welcome to SE:AI!  We like game theory questions, but could you provide some background on dominance tables?  I assume you are referring to the formal concept of [strategic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_dominance) but I'm having trouble intuiting how you model works...

Comment: The image link appears to be broken.